# Problem with adding a new field to an existing model

Tags: field, odoo

I have created a new module in order to add a field to a view but i have this error: "the field 'cin' does not exist

my client.xml code:

```
<record id="view_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <!-- Leave the 'arch' field open -->
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- Put your custom field and its position inside the 'arch' field.
             Use 'xpath' tag to create a more precise positioning -->
       <xpath expr="//group/group/field[@name='name']" position="after">
            <field name="cin"/>
        </xpath>
    <!-- Now, close the 'arch' field -->
    </field>
</record>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: my client.py code:                                                                                                                                    from odoo import models, fields


class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    cin = fields.Char('cin')

Comment: Your client.py looks good. Have you declared this file in __init__.py? Also you need to restart your odoo service after making changes to py files.

Comment: in my models/init.py:    from .import client
from .import models

Comment: in my init.py:    from .import models

Comment: have restarted odoo service and thhen upgraded the module?

Comment: yes but there is the same problem

Comment: I noticed that when I add an existing field( the same parameters) I don't have any problems but when I try to add a new field I get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the following steps:

There are two ways you can add new fields to res.partner model.

1. Uninstall the module. Then add new fields in python and xml file and then restart the server. After server restart install the module again.
2. But if you don't want to uninstall the module then First remove the new fields from xml and python files. Restart the server. Goto odoo apps page and open the module to upgrade. Don't click the upgrade button. Just keep it open. Then add the new fields in python and xml files and restart odoo services. After server restart click on upgrade button. In this way new fields will be added.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Finally it works, but there is no logic in this procedure. I will do this each time I need to add a field??

Comment: You will have to follow these steps each time whenever you add new field in res.partner table. As we know res_partner model is the base and it loads when you open up the odoo.

Comment: but even when I try to add a field in other modules I have the same problem

Comment: No. In other tables like hr_employee,sale_order etc, if you add new field you will have to restart the server and then upgrade the module. This issue is only with res_partner model.